# Check for duplicate 'id' values in a HTML page

Tags: html, css, web-development, duplicate-content

I am developing a web application and I would like to check for duplicate `id` values in a HTML page. I am running the application on my local machine.

There is a way to do that?

P.S.: I am using Firefox and Firebug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The W3C's [validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) tool will report duplicate IDs. To test your code:

1. Copy the generated source code to your clipboard.
2. Visit http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input
3. Paste your markup into the box and hit 'Check'.

You can test it with the following code if you wish:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test">Test div</div>
        <div id="test">Test div 2</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This produces the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Run this code on your browser’s JavaScript console:-

```
(function findDuplicateIds() {
    var ids = {};
    var all = document.all || document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = 0, l = all.length; i < l; i++) {
        var id = all[i].id;
        if (id) {
            if (ids[id]) {
                console.log("Duplicate id: #" + id);
            } else {
                ids[id] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Is there a way to check for duplicates of a particular id that avoids iterating through all elements?

Comment: To answer my own question, this appears to work:  document.querySelectorAll("[id='test']")

Comment: `all` is now deprecated. Care to modify?  Tweaked this and VERY helpful. Somehow I have turned off duplicate `id` checking in my IDE and this saved me big time. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

1. http://validator.w3.org/check
2. If you have [Web Developer Toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) installed, you can use it to contact the above service directly from browser: Tools -> Validate Local HTML
3. Some developer tools (like PhpStorm/WebStorm) automatically perform such validation.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/). It will tell you if there are duplicated ids.
If your site is not online, use Opera. They have a nice feature that uploads the page in order to validate it.

- Right click on the page
- Validate

[image]
[image]